# How do I solve the npm start error in vs code?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I made a new folder name React in which I write react code in vs code If I do npm start then it works fine but if I open a another folder in vs code for coding in other languages and then again open my react folder and do npm start then It throws an below error

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\React Js\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\React Js\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-30T18_04_51_367Z-debug.log
```

so what should I do??

Comment: Does `C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\React Js\package.json` exists ? I mean, is the `C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\React Js` folder where your React code supposed to be ?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the `npm start` command is not issued with the correct [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), so it doesn't find the files it needs.

> so what should I do??

Use a real editor (emacs for example) on a real operating system (gnu/linux for example). :D

Joke aside, the answer is : you should make sure the `npm start` is issued in the folder your react code is. So just do `npm start` when you open the right project. Or make sure you're in the right working directory one way or another (switching project in VSCode, or type the command in a terminal at the right current directory, etc).

Answer (score 0):

When on Windows , you can't link your project on desktop - windows will prevent your IDE to get files in those directories (desktop, documents, program files, etc.).

Create some directory easy to locate e. g. C:/dev/project

Comment: Really ?! I'm no windows expert at all, but that surprised me a lot ! Is it new behavior ? I worked briefly with windows in a past job and could open stuff in Desktop folder IIRC... And why then could he open files and do `npm start` just fine the first time ??